# How to stop SwiftUI section in List from flickering?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

### Explanation of Problem:

New beginner in iOS SwiftUI here! I am currently building a list with a toggle and some text.

Unfortunately each time the toggle has its binary value changed - the list flashes briefly. How do I solve this issue?

### Animated Screenshot:

[image: problem_screenshot]

### Current SwiftUI Code:

```
ForEach(models, id: \.self) 
{ model in
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 1) 
    {
        Toggle("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", isOn: model.enabled.didSet 
        { isOn in
            model.doSomeLogicWithThis(enabled: isOn)
        })

        if model.hasDescr
        {
            Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.").multilineTextAlignment(.leading).foregroundColor(.gray).font(.footnote)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Asperi Are you saying my problem is because the toggles are not mutually exclusive? I thought they are? Since they all have their own separate callback instance, no?

Comment: How is your model declared ? What do you change in model in callback ? Does this happen when you do not call callback?

Comment: Needed minimal reproducible example

Comment: how is your model declared ?

Comment: @PtitXav The callback is irrelevant to the issue. It is only used for illustrative purposes. Even if we removed the line `model.doSomeLogicWithThis(enabled: isOn)` the problem still persists.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri The model implements the `ObservableObject` protocol. Is this a problem?

Comment: if your view is direct owner of model, it should be a state object'